# Break mysql_num_rows into 6x4

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

Pretty much I have a code like below that I'm trying to add `</tr><tr>` to after every 6 results.

```
echo "<table><tr>";

$query="SELECT * WHERE id='$id' ORDER BY date ASC";
$result=mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($rts = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$cdata1 = $rts['cdata1'];
$cdata2 = $rts['cdata2'];

echo "<td>$cdata1 and $cdata2</td>";

}
}else{
echo "<td>no results</td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: `to after every 6 results` - so, just count to 6. Can you increment a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<table><tr>";

$query="SELECT * WHERE id='$id' ORDER BY date ASC";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$i = 0;

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($rts = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$cdata1 = $rts['cdata1'];
$cdata2 = $rts['cdata2'];

echo "<td>$cdata1 and $cdata2</td>";

if(++$i % 6 == 0) {
   echo '</tr><tr>';
}

}
}else{
echo "<td>no results</td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

**UPD:**

Whats means `if(++$i % 6 == 0)` code:

1. `++$i` equals `$i = $i + 1;`
2. `$i % 6` means `$i modulo 6`
3. If $i modulo 6 equals 0 then echo `</tr><tr>`

So we can write it as:

```
$i = $i + 1;
if($i % 6 == 0) {
   echo '</tr><tr>';
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: Dude!!! Virtual hug and come in for the real thing. Thank You :) I had something somewhat like it, but wasn't getting it right. Thanks. Can you explain the if(++$i % 6 == 0) { part.